# Want to remove curly bracers from a string

Tags: javascript, json

I did a search through the site, but it's still not working.

```
var blah2 = JSON.stringify({foo: 123, bar: <x><y></y></x>, baz: 123});
```

this is what I tried:

```
blah2.replace(/[{}]/g, "");
```

this is what it the string comes out to:

```
got "{\"baz\":123,\"foo\":123}"
```

(i know this is probably a newb question, but this is my first time working with javascript and i just don't know what i'm missing)

Comment: why would you remove the `{}`?

Comment: because i'm going to split it with the comma so it turns into an array, and so when I sort it, I dont want to sort it according to the { and }

Comment: Silly question, but why are you trying to remove curly braces from a JSON expression?

Comment: `JSON.stringify({foo: 123, bar: <x><y></y></x>, baz: 123});` results in an error btw, are you sure that code is right?

Comment: see my first comment here.  let me know if you have a better solution to that =)

Comment: ya, it's deep in the Firefox Javascripting code.. i dont fully understand it, but i'm attempting to fix this bug:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=708794%C2%A0

Comment: @nocturn4ltoyou Maybe you mean `bar: "<x><y></y></x>"`?

Comment: full code of file here if you guys are interested..

http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1650846

Comment: It should be `bar: "<x><y></y></x>"`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Javascript strings are immutable. When you call `blah2.replace`, you are not replacing something inside `blah2`, you are creating a new string. What you probably want is:

```
blah2 = blah2.replace(/[{}]/g, '');
```

Comment: i would up vote you but it wont' let me.  TYVM!!! trying to fix a bug in Firefox, was driving me nuts.  ty.  will accept answer in 10 min when it lets me

Answer (score 0):

> because i'm going to split it with the comma so it turns into an
>   array, and so when I sort it, I dont want to sort it according to the
>   { and }

zi42 has already given you the correct answer.

But Since you have written as quoted above, looks like what you want is really to sort data and split it in an array; in this case, parsing/splitting it at the comma, etc, is a long way to go about it.  Here's another way to think about it:

```
var data = {foo: 123, bar: <x><y></y></x>, baz: 123};
var key;
var dataSorted = []; // Create an empty array

for (key in data) {  // Iterate through each key of the JSON data
  dataSorted.push(key);
}

dataSorted.sort();
```

Now you have the data sorted.  When you want to use it, you can use it like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < dataSorted.length; i++) {
  var key = dataSorted[i];
  // Now you do whatever you need with sorted data. eg:
  console.log("Key is: " + key + ", value is: " + data[key]);
}
```